# Can Google Calendar extended properties be lists?

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I want to add a set of extendedProperties to a Google Calendar event. I want some of those properties be lists. As (in python),

```
event = {
         ..., # standard properties
         "extendedProperties": {
                "shared": {
                    "max_crew": 3,
                    "crew_list": [
                        "crew1@example.com",
                        "crew2@example.com",
                        ],
                }
            }
           ...
         }
```

This creates the max_crew property but not the crew_list property.

Any way to do this? Or do I need to use a parse-able string (max 1024 chars)?

Answer (score 1):

Hybor confirms my observation that the interface does not support a list as a value. Shortsighted, imho, but so it goes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way: [explained in Google Calendar's guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/extended-properties) and [reference](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch).

And in Python first create a dictionary for your extra fields.

`body = {
  "extendedProperties": {
    "private": {
      "petsAllowed": "yes"
    }
  }
}`
Then make a request with:
`service.events().patch(calendarId='calendar_id', eventId='event_id', body=body).execute()`

If it is successful, it will return the updated event.

Comment: What I want is a list as the value of the attribute. In hybor's example that means that the "petsAllowed" attribute would equal ["cats", "dogs", "birds"]. In my testing, that did not work. Is there a way it can work?

Comment: It works as a key value. I do not think there is a way it can work with list.